# Como abrir una pagina en una nueva pestaña al hacer click en un boton con data-toogle dropdowm

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una lista (table) generada a través del resultado de una consulta , cada row tiene un boton que despliega una lista de opciones. Necesito que al desplegar esas opciones se abra un enlace en una pestaña nueva, si quito el valor dropdown de la propiedad data-toggle del button el enlace se abre pero no despliega la lista.

El codigo de la lista/tabla es:

```
$.each(data.trabajos, function( i, item ) {
        var link ="http://enlace_a_abrir";
        var tr =  `<tr data="${item.id}">
                        <td>${item.Hora}</td> 
                        <td>${item.Apellido}  ${item.Nombres}</td>
                        <td>${item.Documento_Numero}</td>
                        <td>Sin Verificar</td>
                        <td data-title='Acciones'>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle btn-sl btn-verificar" type="button"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" link="${link}">
                                    Verificar
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end item-dropdownMenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item item-sl"
                                        href="#"
                                        target="_blank">Correcto</a>
                                         <a class="dropdown-item item-sl" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#">Reportar</a>
                                </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr> `;
         $('.table > tbody').append(tr);            
    });// end each
```

> 

Intento mostrar un mensaje en consola al hacer click en el boton, pero como mencioné, al tener el comportamiento de desplegar, no abre la otra pagina.

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-verificar"', function(e){
    console.log('works');
});
```

Como podría combinar ambas acciones? no conozco mucho de data-toggle y data-target. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si intentas algo así en tu button dropdown: `<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" onclick="window.open('https://google.com');">
    Dropdown link
  </button>`

Comment: No funciona, al tener  data-toggle="dropdown" no permite crear otros comportamientos,

Comment: Estás seguro? Porque lo acabo de probar y me funciona sin problema, abre la página en una nueva pestaña. Edita tu pregunta y crea un [example]

Comment: Estoy seguro, si me despliega el menu, no abre la pagina.
Abre la pagina  si quito el data-toggle, pero no despliega el menu.
Como creo el ejemplo que se pueda probar?
Y si respondes con el ejemplo que a ti te funciona?

Comment: El editor de SOes no permite abrir nuevas ventanas, pero puedes probar el código en codepen: https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/OJvGmxd

Comment: los elementos de la tabla que tienen un boton como ultimo <td> son creados despues de que la pagina terminó de cargar. 
Esa es la diferencia que encuentro entre el codigo que pruebo y tu ejemplo.